# Box Rectangle Calculation for Arc

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, html

For common MoveTo(x0, y0), ArcTo(x1, y1, x2, y2, radius) methods;
After a drawing process how can i calculate box rectangle for drawn path with known x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2 and radius values ?

Comment: Where is the ArcTo function defined? The meaning of x1, y1, x2, y2 are ambiguous without the api docs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pie Slice Bounding Rectangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201750/pie-slice-bounding-rectangle)

Answer (score 0):

Are MoveTo and ArcTo here similar to the PostScript commands moveto and arct or arcto?  If so, you will have to calculate where the line between (x0,y0) and (x1, y1) intersects the line between (x1, y2) and (x2, y2), then compute the distance along these lines to the endpoints of the arc, find the center of the arc, then apply the techniques in the post linked to by Unreason.  It is not a simple calculation.  You might want to refer to a linear algebra textbook that deals with this kind of geometry.