# Pie slice bounding rectangle

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, bounding-box

How can I calculate a pie slice bounding rectangle. Radius (r), center point (x0, y0) , StartAngle (a0), EndAngle (a1) and drawDirection (clockwise or counterclockwise) variables are known.

Answer (score 7):

Compute the points at the end of the arc edge, the point at the center of the slice and any of the four extreme points (angles 0, 90, 180 and 270) if they are contained within the sweep angle. Then all you have to do is iterate over all the points and find the minimum and maximum x and y values.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

HTH!

Comment: Though helpful, these corner values assume the slice resides within a single quadrant.